# Prove that $a+\frac{1}{b}>2$ or $b+\frac{1}{a}>2$ for two strict positive numbers

Tags: calculus, inequality

Another Olympiad Problem, let $x$ and $a$ and $b$ be strictly real positive numbers.

1. Prove that   $x$+$\frac{1}{x}$$>$$2$ **(proven)**
2. Then conclude that   $a$+$\frac{1}{b}$$>$$2$  or
   $b$+$\frac{1}{a}$$>$$2$

For the second question, I know I am supposed to replace $x$ with a number in function of $a$ and $b$ , but I can't find it .

if we replace $x$ by $ab$ we still have a problem.

$ab$+$\frac{1}{ab}$$+2>$$4$ , we can't just conclude that $a$+$\frac{1}{b}$$>$$2$  or         $b$+$\frac{1}{a}$$>$$2$

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: There was an answer with a hint by Andre Nicolas that looked fine to me, not sure why it was deleted...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes, the first version of his answer was perfect.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Did the answer get vandalized?

Comment: What about $a = b = 1$?

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Note that 
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{b}\right)\left(b+\frac{1}{a}\right)=ab+\frac{1}{ab}+2.$$

Answer (score 8):

Your first statement $x + \frac 1x > 2$ is not fully correct, you have
$$
 x + \frac 1x \ge 2
$$
for $x > 0$, with equality exactly for $x = 1$.

And as the example $a=b=1$ shows, you can only conclude that
$$ 
a+\frac{1}{b} \ge 2 \quad \text{ or } \quad b+\frac{1}{a} \ge 2 \, .
$$
which is your claim with $\ge$ instead of $>$.

This follows from (similar to André's solution):
$$
\left(a+\frac{1}{b}\right) + \left(b+\frac{1}{a}\right)= a + \frac 1a + b + \frac 1b \ge 2 + 2 = 4
$$
(with equality exactly for $a=b=1$),
so at least one term on the left-hand side must be greater or equal
to $2$.

If $a$ and $b$ are not both equal to one then you can conclude that
$$ 
a+\frac{1}{b} > 2 \quad \text{ or } \quad b+\frac{1}{a} > 2 \, .
$$

Comment: Then finish it off with some nice Pigeonhole principle!

Comment: what's a Pigeonhole principle if I might ask ?

Comment: Nice way, simpler than mine.

Comment: @user2161721: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle. Here: The sum of two terms is greater or equal to 4, then at least one term must be greater or equal to 2.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thank you, but your solution inspired me, and it is quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different.

If $a = b$ then $a + 1/b =  b + 1/a =a + 1/a \ge 2$.

If $a > b$ then $a + 1/b > a + 1/a \ge 2$.

If $a < b$ then $b + 1/a > b + 1/b \ge 2$.

(If $a = b = 1$ then $a + 1/b = 2$. Otherwise $a + 1/b > 2$ or $b + 1/a > 2$ or both.)

Comment: You could even simplify it to two cases: $a \ge b$ and $a < b$.

Comment: True.  I was going to do a wolog but it was short enough it was easier to just do it.

Comment: Sure. I really like this, as it makes a more precise statement (*which* term is $> 2$).

Answer (score 0):

Since you already settled the case $a=b$ in the first part of the question, we may assume without loss of generality that $a<b$.

Therefore we have $b+\dfrac{1}{a} > b +  \dfrac{1}{b} \geq 2$, which yields the required result.

Comment: Isn't this the same as fleablood's approach?

Comment: Yes, it is *essentially* the same, the only difference is i assumed without loss of generality that $a>b$, which liberated me from taking cases (as fleablood did).