# If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, how can I prove that either $a + \frac{1}{b}$ or $b + \frac{1}{a}$ must be greater than or equal to 2?

Tags: inequality

If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, how can I prove that either $a + \frac{1}{b}$ or $b + \frac{1}{a}$ must be greater than or equal to 2?
My approach: I know that $a + \frac{1}{a} \geq 2$ and $b + \frac{1}{b} \geq 2$, so I added both of the inequalities and rearranged the terms to get: $a + \frac{1}{b} + b + \frac{1}{a} \geq 4$, but I don't know how to continue from that point.

Comment: Either $a+\frac1b\ge2$, in which case you're done, or $a+\frac1b<2$, i.e. $-a-\frac1b\gt-2$, and add that to what you got

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1649513/42969

Comment: From the link given in the comment of @MartinR, you know that $~\displaystyle ab + \frac{1}{ab} \geq 2.~$  So, you can now prove that $$\left(a + \frac{1}{b}\right) \times \left(b + \frac{1}{a}\right) \geq 4.$$  So, you have two positive numbers, $~u~$ and $~v~$ such that $~u \times v \geq 4.~$  Therefore, it is impossible for both $~u~$ and $~v~$ to be less than $~2.$

Comment: Re previous comment, note that with $~x > 0,~$ you have that $$(x-1)^2 \geq 0 \implies x^2 + 1 \geq 2x \implies x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2.$$

Comment: If $a\ge b$ then $a+{1\over b}\ge b+{1\over b}\ge 2.$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that both sums are strictly less than $2$, so their sum is less than $4$. But you already proved that their sum must be greater than or equal to $4$. This is a contradiction, so the assumption is wrong. Therefore, one of them must be greater than or equal to $2$.